# Symfony2 dynamic form fields

Tags: php, javascript, forms, symfony

I would like to create a form in Symfony2 which displays a set of radio buttons depending on the selected value in a combo-box belonging to the same form.
I have not been able to find a suitable solution in Symfony2 that would allow me to have this functionality.
Is there any way to use the Symfony2 framework at least for part of the implementation or should I generate the form manually?

Comment: @Bogdan It sounds like what you're trying to do is dynamic HTML (the radio buttons will change without a page refresh when someone selects the value from the combo-box) correct?

Comment: @Matt Yes, you are correct. I don't expect Symfony to provide me with a specific solution but from past experiences with this framework I've learned that it can prove somewhat useful even when JavaScript is involved. A good example is the collection form type which inserts a prototype which can be used to generate as many fields of the same type as needed by means of JavaScript.

Comment: @Yehonatan you're way off the mark there; frameworks are **EXTREMELY** useful, however not everyone is an immediate expert at them or can incorporate multiple facets of web development. Frameworks speed up development, help improve security and make life easier (for the most part) for the people writing the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is AJAX. This can be implemented with straight javascript or jQuery (jQuery is much cleaner and easier to use).

Here's a jQuery stub for you to get an idea of what has to happen:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#mySelect').change(function() {
        $.post('backgroundScript.php', {
            val: $(this).val()
        }, function(data) {
            $('#radioDiv').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you're not familiar with AJAX & jQuery, I'll explain what's going on. `$('#mySelect')` is almost the equivalent of javascript's `getElementById()` function. They are **NOT** the same functionality (jQuery uses the same notations as css to find the elements you're looking for), but this will return the element with `mySelect` as its id attribute.

`.change()` sets the onChange event handler to the `function()` defined within the brackets.  `$.post` is jQuery shorthand for performing an AJAX `post` (as opposed to a `get`), that is sent to *backgroundScript.php* without a page load. When *backgroundScript.php* returns with a 200 status (i.e. "everything's OK, here's my output") it will perform the callback function `function(data)`.

*backgroundScript.php* will receive `val` as a $_POST variable and do "something" to determine which radio buttons should be displayed, then will write output to the screen.

**EDIT (more info):**

*backgroundScript.php* should look something like this if you're determining the radio buttons based on a database. ***Keep in mind that this is not written with security or consideration of deprecated functions in mind (e.g. `mysql_*`), just functionality***:

```
<?php
// backgroundScript.php
$masterVal = $_POST['val'];
$output = "";

$query = "SELECT bt.button_value, bt.button_label
    FROM button_table as bt
    WHERE bt.button_master_id = " . $masterVal;

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= "<input type='radio' name='radioGroup' value='" . 
        $row['button_value'] . "' /> " . $row['button_label'];
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: I see, so this queries a PHP script which, by means of Symfony2, can return the proper form, right?  If I got this right, I would have to hard-code the sets of options available in form type objects. I hate to push it but what if the available options for each selection in the combo should be retrieved from the database?

Comment: Ok, you've already given me an acceptable answer so I'll mark your solution as accepted. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: @Bogdan for more info on jQuery, check out W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the symfony2 form builder, which permits to construct forms programmatically.

This would be possible if you could determine the entity before the construction of the form...